# Earphone jack not working on Samsung All-in-one PC

Tags: alsa

I have looked at the answers given in the forum, but it seems one needs pc-specific solutions?

Ubuntu 15.10 installed on a Samsung DP500A2D All-in-one-pc

Here are the alsa info:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=61d5e9fb29827a2b5b4b3b321eced28396b34d64

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System Settings** > **Audio** and see if your earphone jack is there. If it is, select it, the audio should work.

Comment: Hi Mario

Thnx for feedback. Will look next time I am at the pc .. it is at my sister's .. If you are referring to options under the 'Output' tab under sound settings, I do not remember such an option though? I seem to remember there was only one option.

Gustav